# Increase the last element in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I want to implement a function that takes a `tuple` of `int`s and increases the last element by 1:

```
inc((0,0,0,1))==(0,0,0,2)
inc((1,2,3))==(1,2,4)
```

This is what I came up with:

```
def inc(t):
   l=list(t)
   l[-1]+=1
   return tuple(l)
```

Can this be done in a more compact way (and maybe without the conversion to list) ?

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted but do you have to use tuples for this ? They are, you know, immutable.

Comment: @percusse, I have a feeling this could be done with a one liner

Comment: use mutable sequences for modifying elements

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am not modifying elements, I am creating a copy, there is a reason why I am using a tuple

Comment: Without the *mutable* lingo, you cannot modify a tuple value without creating a new one. You can instead use lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple cannot be modified in-place.  If it's very important to use the `tuple` type rather than a mutable sequence, then the following code will do what you want without converting:

```
def inc(t):
    return t[:-1] + (t[-1] + 1,)
```

Note that it has to create three new tuples in order to accomplish this. I don't know that the overhead involved in that is going to be any smaller than the overhead in converting to & from `list`.

Comment: Nicely done, avoiding lists, and good commentary on your code's strengths and weaknesses.